# How to select HTML element by id that is a number in beatiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to select an HTML element with an id that is a number, ie. `<div id=27047243>`

When I try to use the select method like this `soup.select("#27047243")` I get an error that says *Malformed id selector*

I figured I need to escape the number somehow, I tried like this `soup.select(r"#\3{number}"` but even though I did not get the error anymore, I could not get the element

I know I could use the find method `soup.find(id="27047243")` and that works, but the problem is I need to go deeper into nested elements so I want to know if there is a way how to do this using 'select' so I can use CSS selectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `div[id="27047243"]`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<div id=27047243>
I want this.
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")
print(soup.select_one('div[id="27047243"]'))
```

Prints:

```html
<div id="27047243">
I want this.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
soup.select_one('div#27047243')
```